# How to prove this binary operation?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let (G, ∗) be a group and a,b € G.

Show that (a✻b)^-1 = a^-1✻b^-1 if and only if a✻b=b✻a

I could not solve this, how can ve prove it?

a^-1 means inverse of a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll show the left to right implication, you can do the right to left.

Suppose $(a*b)^{-1}=a^{-1}*b^{-1}$, then $e=(a*b)^{-1}*(a*b)=(a^{-1}*b^{-1})*(a*b)$ and so $b*(a*e)=b*(a*(a^{-1}*b^{-1})*(a*b))$. By associativity and cancellation we then get $b*a=e*(a*b)=a*b$ as required.